# Get only the length of mongoose virtual populate

Tags: database, mongoose, schema, virtual, populate

I would like to know if there is a way in Mongoose of getting the number of matching localField/foreignField as virtual field, without retrieving all the documents through virtual population.

Example:

```
const ForumThreadSchema = new Schema({
    code: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    title: { type: String, min: [10, 'Too short title'], max: [200, 'Too long title'], required: true },
    description: { type: String, min: [10, 'Too short description'], max: [2000, 'Too long description'], required: true },
    creation_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
    updated_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
    _authorId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    _forumId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Forum', required: true }
}, {
    collection: 'ForumThreads',
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

const ForumMessageSchema = new Schema({
    code: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    content: { type: String, min: [10, 'Too short message content'], max: [2000, 'Too long message content'], required: true },
    creation_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
    update_date: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
    _authorId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    _forumThreadId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ForumThread', required: true },
    _parentMessageId: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ForumMessage' }
}, {
    collection: 'ForumMessages'
});
```

The virtual populate on the forum thread schema retrieves me all the message documents. I need a virtual field with only their number if possible.

```
ForumThreadSchema
.virtual('messages', {
    ref: 'ForumMessage',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: '_forumThreadId'
});

ForumThreadSchema
.virtual('messages_count')
.get(function() {
    return this.messages.length;
});
```

The second virtual only works if the population of the first one is done.
I also want to mantain the virtual populate but I would like to find a way of getting the number of matching documents without use it (in server APIs that not need all message documents but only their size).
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add the count option:

```
ForumThreadSchema
.virtual('messages_count', {
    ref: 'ForumMessage',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: '_forumThreadId',
    count: true
});
```

And then when you can populate just the count:

```
ForumThread.find({}).populate('messages_count')
```

Doc: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#count